# How to calculate probability distribution for the duration of recurring tournament?

Tags: probability

I've hit an interesting general problem and cannot work it out. I would be grateful for any pointers:

The problem: 5 players are randomly assigned a number x=1-5.  A player compares his number with another random player.  The player with the lower score leaves and the player with the higher score goes into the next round and repeats the tournament. What is the probability that player i goes out in round 1, 2, 3 or 4

Current strategy: Calculate the probability of winning with number x, multiply by the probability of getting that number and sum to find the probability of winning that round.

For round 1, P(winning with x=1)=0, P(winning with x=2)=1/4, P(winning with x=3)=2/4 etc. The probability of getting any number x is 1/5, so the probability of succeeding in round 1 is (1/5 x 0)+(1/5 x 1/4)+(1/5 x 2/4)+(1/5 x 3/4)+(1/5 x 4/4)

This sums to 0.5 so the probability of going out in round 1 is (1-0.5) = 0.5.

For the next round, I have to generate the probabilities of having numbers 2,3,4,5 and this is where I am getting stuck.  It will no longer be uniform as there will e.g be a higher probability that x=4 reached round 2 than x=2 but I cannot work this out.

Comment: Your description doesn't seem to work. The way you have it, every time a player compares their number with another, one is eliminated (so not able to be compared again) and the other goes to the next round (so not able to be compared again with someone from this round) - but there's an odd number of players in the first round, which means one player is left over. That player can't compare their value with anyone else, because they're all either eliminated or through to another round.

Comment: Apologies if not clear. An example.  Player 1 picks number 4.  In round 1, he faces player 3 who picked number 2.  Player 1 goes through, player 3 goes out. In round 2, player 1 faces player 4 who picked number 5.  Player 1 goes out.  The duration of the game would be 2 rounds (x=2). I am looking for the probabilities of X where x=1-4 for a randomly picked player.